# How connect to embedded activeMQ in spring boot using Hawtio?

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, stomp, hawtio

I have spring boot application contains embedded activeMQ, i want to connect to web console using hawtio but not able to connect .
i do the following steps  :

1-in cmd  "java -jar hawtio-app-1.5.7.jar".

2- trying connect to **Host** :  localhost **port** : 1099 **Path** : /api/jolokia
but not working return the following  :

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (localhost:1099 failed to respond)**

Pom.xml

```
<!-- Starter for building web, including RESTful, applications using Spring 
MVC. Uses Tomcat as the default embedded container -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- the embedded container dependencies as “provided” -->

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Logging libraries -->
<dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- WebSocket libraries -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- reactor project libraries -->
<dependency>
<groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
<artifactId>reactor-bus</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
<artifactId>reactor-net</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
<artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>io.netty</groupId>
<artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
<version>4.0.33.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Email -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
<artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
<artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
<artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
<version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
<artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
<version>3.3.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
<artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
<artifactId>activemq-stomp</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
<artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>




</dependencies>

<repositories>
<repository>
<id>spring-snapshots</id>
<name>Spring Snapshots</name>
<url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>
</repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
<id>spring-releases</id>
<name>Spring Releases</name>
<url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<source>${jdk.version}</source>
<target>${jdk.version}</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>repackage</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

the below log startup   :

```
`2018-02-13;00:31:26.976 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
                o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean.onStartup(190) - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-02-13;00:31:27.016 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
                o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean.configure(258) - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-13;00:31:27.019 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
                o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean.configure(258) - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-13;00:31:27.021 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
                o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean.configure(258) - Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-13;00:31:27.022 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
                o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean.configure(258) - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-13;00:31:28.938 [main] INFO 
                o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize(165) - Initializing ExecutorService  'clientInboundChannelExecutor'
2018-02-13;00:31:28.976 [main] INFO 
                o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize(165) - Initializing ExecutorService  'clientOutboundChannelExecutor'
2018-02-13;00:31:29.434 [main] INFO 
                o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize(165) - Initializing ExecutorService  'messageBrokerTaskScheduler'
2018-02-13;00:31:29.567 [main] INFO 
                o.s.w.s.s.s.WebSocketHandlerMapping.registerHandler(362) - Mapped URL path [/websocket/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler]
2018-02-13;00:31:29.627 [main] INFO 
                o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize(165) - Initializing ExecutorService  'brokerChannelExecutor'
2018-02-13;00:31:30.895 [main] WARN 
                o.a.activemq.broker.BrokerService.checkMemorySystemUsageLimits(2146) - Memory Usage for the Broker (1024mb) is more than the maximum available for the JVM: 512 mb - resetting to 70% of maximum available: 358 mb
2018-02-13;00:31:31.096 [main] INFO 
                o.a.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartPersistenceAdapter(671) - Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[C:\Users\anash\git\Notfication\activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB]
2018-02-13;00:31:31.111 [JMX connector] INFO 
                o.a.a.broker.jmx.ManagementContext.run(155) - JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
2018-02-13;00:31:31.721 [main] INFO 
                o.a.a.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase.read(191) - KahaDB is version 6
2018-02-13;00:31:31.747 [main] INFO 
                o.a.a.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase.recover(678) - Recovering from the journal @1:1026194
2018-02-13;00:31:31.768 [main] INFO 
                o.a.a.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase.recover(706) - Recovery replayed 253 operations from the journal in 0.037 seconds.
2018-02-13;00:31:31.965 [main] INFO 
                o.a.a.s.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl.doStart(371) - PListStore:[C:\Users\anash\git\Notfication\activemq-data\localhost\tmp_storage] started
2018-02-13;00:31:32.136 [main] INFO 
                o.a.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartBroker(734) - Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.5 (localhost, ID:SPS-Anash-49217-1518474691990-0:1) is starting
2018-02-13;00:31:32.159 [main] INFO 
                o.a.a.t.TransportServerThreadSupport.doStart(69) - Listening for connections at: stomp://127.0.0.1:61613
2018-02-13;00:31:32.160 [main] INFO 
                o.a.a.broker.TransportConnector.start(263) - Connector stomp://127.0.0.1:61613 started
2018-02-13;00:31:32.164 [main] INFO 
                o.a.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartBroker(761) - Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.5 (localhost, ID:SPS-Anash-49217-1518474691990-0:1) started
2018-02-13;00:31:32.165 [main] INFO 
                o.a.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartBroker(762) - For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
2018-02-13;00:31:32.169 [main] WARN `
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Jolokia endpoint on your Spring Boot app and make it accessible outside of the app.

To do so, firstly you need to add `spring-boot-actuator` in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then in your `application.properties`, disable sensitivity of the Jolokia endpoint:

```
endpoints.jolokia.sensitive = false
```

Now you should be able to connect to Jolokia at: http://localhost:8080/jolokia Try connecting to it from your hawtio console.

FYI, here you can find a working example of hawtio integration with a Spring Boot app:
https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/hawtio-1.5.7/hawtio-sample-springboot/

Comment: i added `<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
  <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
 </dependency>` and  `endpoints.jolokia.sensitive = false` but not working **"http://localhost:8080/jolokia "**